# Expected value of max of two selections

Tags: statistics

Not a homework problem, just a question from life.

Suppose I'm choosing a cart at the grocery store. I can rank these carts from 1 to N, with 1 being the best and N being the worst. If I take the first cart I see, I would expect it to be ranked somewhere in the middle. I believe this amounts to assuming the carts form a discrete uniform distribution from 1 to N, where N is the number of carts. I believe I'm saying that the expected value of my cart's rank would therefore be $\frac{N}{2}$, or 50 with N = 100.

However, there is another strategy I could use to choose a cart. I could compare the first two carts I see and take the best. In my own simulations, this seems to improve my ranking (with N = 100) to about position 33. If I compare 3 carts instead, this seems to improve my ranking to about position 25. This is starting to look to me a bit like $\frac{N}{k}$ where k is the number of choices I'm trying.

My question is, how do you state this question formally and compute the solution? Am I using any of these words correctly?

My code, in case it's interesting:

````
import random
import statistics

n = 100
trials = 100000
attempts = 3

def schema(n, attempts, trials=100000):
    """
    Given `n` carts, compare `attempts` number of carts and see how much this improves
    our life.
    """
    carts = range(n)
    selections = []
    improvements = []

    for i in range(trials):
        choices = random.choices(carts, k=attempts)
        selections.append(min(choices))
        improvements.append(abs(max(choices) - min(choices)))

    return statistics.mean(selections), statistics.mean(improvements)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    selection, improvement = schema(n, attempts, trials=trials)
    print(f"average selected cart quality: {selection}")
    print(f"average improvement: {improvement}")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $1 \le k \le N$, let $X$ represent the highest rank of the carts selected, where $1$ is the highest rank and $N$ the lowest.  You want to compute $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid k, N]$$ which is the expected value of the best ranked cart when $k$ carts are selected from $N$ total.

Since the selected $k$-subset comprises distinct elements from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$ with equal probability, there are $\binom{N}{k}$ possible elementary outcomes.  Of these, the number of outcomes with best rank $x$ is $$\binom{N - x}{k-1},$$ because exactly one of the $k$ carts chosen is rank $x$, leaving $k-1$ choices among $N-x$ carts with worse ranking.  Therefore,

$$\Pr[X = x \mid k, N] = \frac{\binom{N-x}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}}, \quad x \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N-k+1\}.$$

The expected value is $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid k, N] = \sum_{x=1}^{N-k+1} x \Pr[X = x \mid k, N] = \frac{N+1}{k+1},$$ the proof of which I have left as an exercise for the reader.

So for $N = 100$ and $k = 3$, the average rank is $101/4 = 25.25$.  You can confirm this via simulation.  In *Mathematica*, a single command suffices to generate $10^7$ realizations of $X$:

```
Mean[ParallelTable[Min[RandomSample[Range[100], 3]], {10^7}]]
```

A calculation of the standard error shows it is less than $0.01$, so there are enough realizations to show the expected value is not exactly $25$.

Comment: Thank you so much!